# Problems accessing data from a GraphQL query in Javascript with Svelte

Tags: javascript, graphql, svelte

Below I have my working function using a normal REST response that I want to try to convert into a GraphQL version, it fetches a JSON doc from my Phoenix Server and stores the object values from the JSON doc into an object. The problem is, here I can use await and then assign the new object values from the object within the JSON document, but using GraphQL I cannot access this data to assign it because there is no await function as its just a Query. (From what I know)

```
async function updatePageWithNewCompany(company){
        const res = await fetch(`http://localhost:4000/${company}`);
        profile = await res.json();
        profile = profile.companyProfile 
            DashboardStore.update(currentData => {
                return {
                    id: profile.id,
                    companyName: `${profile.company_name}`,
                    averageLength: profile.average_length,
                    } 
                })
```

Ultimately I am asking if there is a way to access and assign data from a GraphQL query in JavaScript so I can manipulate it before displaying it in my frontend Svelte app.

Example of current GraphQL query:

```
import { gql } from '@apollo/client'
import { client } from './apollo';
import { query, setClient } from "svelte-apollo";   

setClient(client)

const GET_COMPANY = gql`
      query{
        companyProfile(){
            companyName
            averageLength
            }
        }
    `;
const response = query(GET_COMPANY)
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a working solution with the help of @Thomas-Hennes

```
import { client } from '../apollo.js';
import { onMount } from "svelte";
import { gql } from '@apollo/client'

export const COMPANY_LIST = gql`
    query {
        listCompanies{
            companyName
        }
     }
  `;

async function listCompanies() {
    await client.query({query: COMPANY_LIST})
          .then(res => {
              companyList.update( currentData => 
              [...res.data.listCompanies.companyName])})
        };

onMount(() =>{
    listCompanies()
})
```

await didn't like being assigned to a variable or having its data manipulated so i used it as a promise instead and manipulated the response.
The below link helped me find the final piece of the puzzle.
https://docs.realm.io/sync/graphql-web-access/using-the-graphql-client

Comment: where is `companyList`?

Comment: @shorif2000 companyList is just a svelte store that I forgot to include in the code above. It would've been at the top as so: 
import {companyList} from "../companyStore.js"

Answer (score 0):

`svelte-apollo` queries return

> a svelte store of promises that resolve as values come in

as stated [in the example query displayed in the documentation](https://github.com/timhall/svelte-apollo#example).

As such, you can exploit that format directly in the script section. Here is an example:

```js
...
async function getCompany() {
  const companyStore = query(GET_COMPANY)
  const company = (await $companyStore).data.companyProfile
  return company  // format will be an object with keys { companyName, averageLength } according to your query
}
...
```

On a side-note I would recommend always getting the `id` of objects in your GraphQL queries as it is usually the key used internally by the Apollo client to manage its cache (unless explicitly stated otherwise).

Comment: Thank you for your reply,

I did try something similar before which led me to ask this question, using your method which should work! the first error I get is this:  

'Stores must be declared at the top level of the component (this may change in a future version of Svelte) svelte(contextual-store)'  

So I moved `const companyStore = query(GET_COMPANY)` outside of the function, then I get an `'await' has no effect on the type of this expression. js(80007)` Error, and then once run the Error is `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: (intermediate value).data is undefined.

Comment: Try do add a simple `let companyStore` declaration at the top level, and change the assignment to `companyStore = query(GET_COMPANY)`, but keep the assignment inside the `getCompany()` function.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I've found a working solution that i've posted as answer.

Comment: i tried this `company` returns undefined and `(await $companyStore).data.companyProfile` is still `loading`